# Accessing Local Database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Microsoft Visual C# 2010 - Adding Data to Local Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720491/microsoft-visual-c-sharp-2010-adding-data-to-local-database)

I'm trying to develop simple Windows Froms application that stores data in local database instead of a `.txt` file. I'm adding local database to my project via `Add new item -> Local Database -> Dataset`. Afterwards, I'm adding a simple table with 3 columns using `Database Explorer` - so far so good.

but then I would like to access this database within my `Form1` class, filling created table by using loop (since I don't want to fill 255 rows manually when they are supposed to be filled with 0's by default), making some queries to get data from database and put some data in database. 

I tried following several tutorials but I always ended up getting an error at

```
con.Open();
```

How should I approach local databases in C#?

Which connection string should I use in this context?

What my code initializing access to database should look like?

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
"Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" +
"User Instance=true;" +
"Integrated Security=true;" +
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.sdf;";
conn.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * From LootServers";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
da.Fill(ds1, "Servers");
DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0];
MessageBox.Show(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
conn.Close();
```

and the error is:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\User1\Documents\VisualStudio 2010\Projects\LootServers\LootServers\bin\Debug\Database.sdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: If you wrote some code and it's not working, it's always helpful to provide the code, or better yet, a Simple, Self-Contained Complete Example, and an explanation of what happens when you try to run it.  That way, we'll be better equipped to understand what's going wrong

Comment: as for helping you go forward with your question, here's a link to a linq-to-sql tutorial:http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx  You might also look into seeing if Sql server management studio is installed, and if it's not, installing it.  it will help you visualizing your database.

Comment: Can you post your code here? what error you are getting on connecting?